# jQuery find and replace <strong> tags before appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

```
$("body").on("click", ".search-results li", function(){

    $(this).appendTo(".creating-wrapper .recipients");

});
```

I want to remove `<strong></strong>` tags which are applied to the text when a user performs a search.

The html being appended looks like:

```
<li class="highlight-off" rel="<?php echo $userID?>">
    <div class="left"><img class="photo" src="<?php echo photo($userID, 35)?>"/></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="name"><?php echo highlight($term,  str_replace("&nbsp;"," ", name($userID)))?></div>

    </div>
</li>
```

Also, one other thing I would also like to do in addition, would be to remove the entire `<div class='left'></div>` and its elements

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simply jQuery magic.

```
var $append = $( this );
    $append.find( 'div.left' ).remove();
    $append.find( 'strong' ).contents().unwrap();

$append.appendTo(".creating-wrapper .recipients");
```

Comment: Almost, however I want the text inside of the <strong></strong> tags to remain there.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$("body").on("click", ".search-results li", function(){
    $(this).find('div.left').remove();
    $(this).find('strong').each(function() {
        $(this).after($(this).text()).remove();
    });
    $(this).appendTo(".creating-wrapper .recipients");
});
```

Comment: Yours removes the div.left, however it doesn't do anything to the strong tags. However, as the answer below does, I don't want the text inside of the strong tags to be rmeoved, just the tags themselves so the text is no longer bold.